# Using powershell to sync services

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I'd like to sync all services and startup processes across my network with a powershell script.
I already have a list of the services i'd like to copy in XML, TXT and HTM format, created by Powershell. My question is how do I push this list to the other PC's using Invoke-Command?
EDIT: This is for a non-domain environment.
Don't worry about the remoting, that's all sorted out.

Or is there any other way?

The services should be configured like the other main PC as well. Like Automatic startup, manual or disabled so i wont have to run the script over and over.. :-)

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like a situation where you should be using Desired State Configuration, GPO, SCCM, or a combination of the above. The tooling already exists to manage this stuff - don't kill yourself reimplementing it.

Comment: That's all for Domain usage, isn't it?

Comment: People still run Windows networks without Active Directory?

Comment: Sadly the company I work for has yet to invest in a fully controlled domain. 80% of the workstations are not registered due to wrong Windows Version.

This will be taken care of in the future but so far it is unclear when.